# Remove symbols while appending in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, parsing

I'm having some parsing issues here. I have a column of Twitter handles, with '@' in front of them, and I'm trying to auto-append them in a URL on the next column.

Example:

| @Bob | https://twitter.com/@Bob |

The code in the second cell is `="https://twitter.com/"&A17`.

How do I either filter out the '@' symbols *or* append beginning from the second character in the string (which I would do with `str[1:]` in Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `RIGHT` and `LEN`.

```
="https://twitter.com/"&RIGHT(A17,LEN(A17)-1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `SUBSTITUTE` to the same effect.

```
="https://twitter.com/"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","")
```

`SUBSTITUTE` may be a better option if the formatting of the Twitter handles in column A is inconsistent at all.